# How to push arrays of a multi-dimensional array to an array of other multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have 2 arrays: students array stores information of students, classes stores list of class with info of class and a list of student in this class. They like:

```
$students = array(array(
'name' => '', 
'gender' => '', 
'birthday'=>''
));

$classes = array(array(
'name' => '',
 'info'=> '',
 'student_list' => ''
));
```

I want each class has 25 students, so i use:

```
$student_arrays = array_chunk($students, 25);
```

but I dont know how to push $student_arrays into $classes. Any help, pls ?

btw, how to i sort $students array with 'name' ?

Comment: you can use a foreach to parse the classess array. 
foreach($classes as $class){ $class['stundet_list'] = $students; }

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the $students array by name field by using usort() function:

```
function sortName($a, $b)
{
    return $a['name'] - $b['name'];
}
usort($students, 'sortName');
```

Now, from what I understand, you want to assign all 25 students to each classes. In that case, we need to a loop for classes.

$class_students is an array which has a key storing the name of the class. And the value is the entire students array.

```
$class_students = array();

foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $class_students[$class] = $students;
}
```